# Intercepting dynamic parallel routes returns 404 only on staging

Tags: reactjs, next.js, app-router

In this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/ecstatic-framework-ymd4mw?file=%2Fapp%2Flandscape%2F%5BcollectionName%5D%2F%5Bphoto%5D%2Fpage.tsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30007356jo87n8jwu%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g20002356jg51kmjal%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30004356juohdl8hn%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30006356j7sotjtmf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltd9s3g20002356jg51kmjal%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g20002356jg51kmjal%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltdadxbd0002356kgwap3xnm%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Flandscape%252F%255BcollectionName%255D%252F%255Bphoto%255D%252Fpage.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltdadxbd0002356kgwap3xnm%2522%257D%252C%2522cltd9s3g30006356j7sotjtmf%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30005356j65uzr4wq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Flandscape%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30006356j7sotjtmf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30005356j65uzr4wq%2522%257D%252C%2522cltd9s3g30004356juohdl8hn%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30003356jw37rmgyp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30004356juohdl8hn%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30003356jw37rmgyp%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) example which has exactly the same routing as my project, you can see that intercepting routes works fine.

If you go to `/landscape` then click on a link, then click on another link; It shows the intercepted route. But on my [staging environment](https://photography-portfolio-sooty.vercel.app/) it simply does not work. If you go to `/landscape`, then select a category and click on a photo it will show a 404, but if you go to the cars category and select photo it will intercept the route.

On my local machine it works fine for both development and production builds the same as they work in the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/ecstatic-framework-ymd4mw?file=%2Fapp%2Flandscape%2F%5BcollectionName%5D%2F%5Bphoto%5D%2Fpage.tsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30007356jo87n8jwu%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g20002356jg51kmjal%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30004356juohdl8hn%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30006356j7sotjtmf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltd9s3g20002356jg51kmjal%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g20002356jg51kmjal%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltdadxbd0002356kgwap3xnm%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Flandscape%252F%255BcollectionName%255D%252F%255Bphoto%255D%252Fpage.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltdadxbd0002356kgwap3xnm%2522%257D%252C%2522cltd9s3g30006356j7sotjtmf%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30005356j65uzr4wq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Flandscape%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30006356j7sotjtmf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30005356j65uzr4wq%2522%257D%252C%2522cltd9s3g30004356juohdl8hn%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30003356jw37rmgyp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30004356juohdl8hn%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltd9s3g30003356jw37rmgyp%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D). I have noticed the following differences inside the url structure when inspecting the network tab:

###### Local machine / CodeSandbox

```bash
/landscape/garda/children/garda/t1zm35rjemmwjkdkxlgi
```

###### Staging Environment

```bash
/landscape/%5BcollectionName%5D/children/%5BcollectionName%5D/enlhqxbojna9dsjajidw
```